# Out-printer command causes endless page counting loop with Zebra GK420d printer

Tags: powershell, zebra-printers

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to send data directly to Zebra GK420d label printer. "Out-Printer" produces endless count of pages and data not being sent to the printer.

Commands:

```sh
"data" | Out-Printer "ZDesigner GK420d"
```

or

```sh
Get-Content C:\barcode.txt | Out-Printer "ZDesigner GK420d"
```

result in producing print job with endless page counting and nothing being printed.

What worked for me was to share Zebra in my network and setting it up as lpt1 port:

```sh
net use lpt1: \\host\Zebra
```

I was able to copy a *.txt file with ZPL contents and it was interpreted correctly by the printer:

```sh
copy barcode.txt lpt1
```

That would work well as a work-around solution, but I'm trying to run this script on a server without admin rights. So sharing a printer or setting lpt1 cannot be done.

I want to be able to send data directly to the printer using PowerShell script, just like it can be done with "Print preferences>Tools>Action>Send command" or in Zebra Setup Utilities > Open Communication With Printer.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you just send "Hello printer" | Out-Printer -name "ZDesigner GK420d" ?
Is the printer set up on a server so that you can use: "Hello printer" | Out-Printer "\\servername\ZDesigner GK420d"?

Comment: Checked both scenarios, in each case I get the loop situation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the Link-OS SDK there is a .NET SDK. This contains an command line exe which could be used from your script.

http://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/pc_net/

Go to the link for "Use the command line"

Answer (score 0):

I added new printer with "Generic \ Text driver" and pointed it to the USB002 port with Zebra printer. I can now use Out-Printer command as intended. Thanks for the answers.